Find unidirectional edges of a given label
There are currently some unidirectional IS_FRIENDS_WITH edges in our graph (where a IS_FRIENDS_WITH b and not vice versa). I want to write a query that will for every such uni-directional edge from a->b, draw a matching edge b IS_FRIENDS_WITH a. At the end of this operation, the intention is that we will know that every IS_FRIENDS_WITH edge has a corresponding incoming edge.
I tried this:
let uniDirectionalEdges = await g
    .V()
    .hasLabel('user')
    .as('outgoingUser')
    .out('IS_FRIENDS_WITH')
    // NOTE: failing here. Attempts to see if the edge already has a corresponding incoming edge.
    .where(__.not(__.out('IS_FRIENDS_WITH').hasId(__.select('outgoingUser').id())))
    // if there is no such edge, add it. I believe this part will work fine.
    .addE('IS_FRIENDS_WITH')
    .to(__.select('outgoingUser'))
    .toList();

It fails with the message: Expected an id that is convertible to String but received class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal.
It appears that I'm failing to compare a vertex later in the traversal to the outgoingUser vertex because of a type issue. I also tried is, which doesn't work and is meant for constant values. What is the right way to compare a vertex to an earlier vertex in the traversal and check for equality? I'm also open to different approaches. I'm just looking to get the job done.

You maybe able to make use of the recipe that is used to find parallel edges.  This doesn't get you 100% there (as parallel edges in the same direction would be detected here, as well):  https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#duplicate-edge
But if you change the outE() in that query to bothE() it could detect multiple edges of the same label regardless of direction.
At least a potential starting point.
